# Anaconda para Pycharm no Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

Pessoal não estou conseguindo acessar, o anaconda no pycharm, primeiro tentei acessar duas bibliotecas e apareceu esse erro.
Bibliotecas:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np
```

erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/moises/Documentos/curso de python/Curso-Ciencia-de-Dados-master/Amostragem/amostragem1.py", line 1, in <module>
import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

E é muito estranho pois nem um novo projeto o ele permite criar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém já passou por isso?

OBS: Eu uso Python3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Anaconda além de ser uma distribuição python é, também, um gerenciador de ambientes virtuais (venvs), ou seja, o ideal é que vc crie um ambiente virtual para cada projeto que vc tiver que trabalhar, assim vc pode ter, por exemplo, um projeto utilizando o python 2.7 com pacotes que só funcionem nessa versão, um outro utilizando o python 3.4 com pandas, scikit, etc.

Voce pode criar esses ambientes virtuais através do pycharm, mas, na minha opinião, não é a melhor maneira de iniciar, pois esconde o que acontece "behind the scenes", vou tentar explanar aqui como funciona fora do pycharm e depois uma maneira de configura-lo para utilizar o ambiente.

**Criando um ambiente:**
Após a instalação do anaconda, escolha um nome para a sua venv, digamos que vc esteja fazendo um curso de django que utiliza o python 3.5 e o django 2.1, vamos considerar o nome para a venv como curso-django, na linha de comando do linux, crie o ambiente assim:

```
conda create -n curso-django python=3.5
```

**Listando os ambientes:**
Para ter certeza que o ambiente foi criado, use o comando `conda-env` para listar
os ambientes disponíveis:

```
$ conda-env list
```

A saída deverá ser algo parecido com isto:

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /home/sidon/miniconda3
curso-django             /home/sidon/miniconda3/envs/curso-django
```

Note que o ambiente em que vc se encontra (ativo) é sinalizado com o asterisco.

**Mudando o ambiente:**
Após a instalação do anaconda, vc sempre estará na "base", sempre que voce acionar a linha de comando, para mudar de ambiente use o comando `source activate`:

```
$ ~/ source activate curso-django
(curso-django) $ ~/
```

Repare que o prompt de comando muda, fica apresentando entre parenteses o ambiente ativo no momento. Use `source deactivate` para voltar para a base.

**Instalando pacotes no ambiente:**
Depois de criado o ambiente voce pode instalar os pacotes que quiser tanto com o proprio anaconda como com o pip, não esqueça de ativar antes o ambiente desejado, por exemplo:

```
~/ $ source activate curso-django
(curso-django) ~/ pip install django==2.1 pandas numpy
```

Voce pode também instalar os pacotes através do pycharm, se quiser.

**Pycharm configurando um projeto para um ambiente:**
Para configurar um projeto para utilizar um ambiente do anacadonda no pycharm vá em: `file/settings/project/projectInterpreter`, se o ambiente que vc deseja não aparecer na lista, clique na engrenagem e na opcao add, escolha 'existing environment' e depois nos 3 pontinhos para procurar o diretorio (Informado pelo comando `$ conda-env list`)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @Sindon's muito obrigado pelo retorno. Eu uso o mint 19. Quando baixei o anaconda diretamente do site ele veio um arquivo com extensão ".sh" Esse conda aí que aparece na tela não sei como instalei.

Comment: segue o nome completo do arquivo que baixei do anaconda: Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-ppc64le.sh

Comment: Quando jogo o que você colocou para instalar o conda: diz que o conda não foi encontrado.

Comment: Mas eu não coloquei comando para instalar o anaconda, tudo que coloquei ai parte do presuposto que vc ja tem o anaconda instalado. Vc instalou o anaconda?

Comment: @Sindon's sua resposta me ajudou a entender como funciona. Estou instalando agora. E depois seguirei o que vc colocou.